# How to call a function when bytes of an array changes?

Tags: c, arrays

If have a very large array, Arr [255]. I'm writing a function which should perform a task whenever any one or more byte in this array has been updated by other functions. Could you help me with the best possible method?

For any change in first 3 bytes of Arr, I can call the function Task() like the following.

```
int main (void)
{
   while (1)
   {
       CheckArrayUpdated ();
   }
}

void CheckArrayUpdated (void)
{
    static char ArrPre [3];

    if (
       (ArrPre [0] != Arr [0]) ||
       (ArrPre [1] != Arr [1]) ||
       (ArrPre [2] != Arr [2]) 
       )
    {
        Task ();

        ArrPre [0] = Arr [0];
        ArrPre [1] = Arr [1];
        ArrPre [2] = Arr [2];
    }
    else;
}
```

How can I do this for the entire array, without consuming much of processing time and increasing the length and size of code?

Comment: Can you modify `Task()` to return a list of changed indexes?

Comment: Hi Jongware, I have no idea which index of the array is getting changed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't access the array directly but use getters/setters:

```
static char arr[255];

char read_arr(int index) {
    return arr[index];
}

void write_arr(int index, char value) {
    if (arr[index] != value) {
        Task();
        arr[index] = value;
    }
}
```

The change is detected as soon as a new (different) value is written to the array, and the `Task()` can be executed immediately. You don't have to check the whole array periodically anymore.

Comment: Hi dlask, I've no clue where this array is getting written. All I have is an array whose bytes are getting changed frequently

Comment: What's your actual environment? A microcontroller program where the array content is modified from interrupt handlers? A multithreading application? What exactly?

Comment: Yes, a microcontroller project in which array content is modified after an interrupt occurs and is written in a seperate .c file. Since I don't know too much about the coding of that particular file, I don't want to disturb that part of the code where the array is getting modified.

Comment: Then you have to use your original approach with a copy of the array. Just the change detection can be simplified in this way: `memcmp(ArrPre, Arr, sizeof(Arr))`. This function returns zero when both arrays are identical, and it returns non-zero if there is a difference.

Comment: Yeah, 'memcmp'. That was really helpful. Lemme check if my compiler support the function. Thanks alot dlask :-)